# Can I get my bcrypt password in plain form through coding?

Tags: bcrypt

I am using bcrypt for encryptign the password and save into DB , but now I need to give access to Admin that he can check anyone password so is it possible to get back in plain form .

```
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB. 
    });
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Can I get my bcrypted password in plain form through coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

> bcrypt is a password hashing function designed by Niels Provos and
>   David Mazières, based on the Blowfish cipher, and presented at USENIX
>   in 1999.

Hashing functions are one-way, so no, you cannot get the plain text password, and if you could, your encryption system would be useless for password storage anyway.